# unable to resolve host "websitename.net": no adddress associated with hostname error

Tags: android, .net, kotlin

I am running the project which is having front end as android using Kotlin and back-end as .net but after running the project on login page after submitting data for signup it giving me this error I have better access to internet and also given permissions in manifest, is there any back-end issue or something else?

Comment: try to add https:// to your website

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't help you if you don't provide some relevant code. I'd say you entered the website wrong in your code.

Comment: taki eddine it is my android app in which this problem arise.